# Maven 3.0.5 -> 3.3.9 SNAPSHOT version change

Tags: java, maven

I recently upgraded Maven from 3.0.5 to 3.3.9.

Ever since, I can't build projects because of dependency failure when trying to find SNAPSHOTs.

The error is:

> Could not find artifact bla:bla:war:9.81.6-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

bla:bla has been built and put to my Archiva repo so I went to check there and I noticed a subtle difference in the version numbers between the project built with Maven 3.0.5 and 3.3.9.

3.0.5

[image: Archiva package built with 3.0.5]

3.3.9

[image: Archiva package built with 3.3.9]

You can see that with the later version of Maven, rather than having a -SNAPSHOT version, i get a timestamped version instead.

Endless Googling hasn't turned up any thing about this change so over to SO for answers!

If i take the full timestamped version specified in Archiva and put it in my POM, then I can build the project but obviously this is not how snapshots are supposed to work.

Comment: First a pom file which causes this? Are you running on command line?

Comment: Example pom http://pastebin.com/3XDh1Tuu. I've run on command line from my Mac and from bamboo build server with same result.